# Can WatiN disable JavaScript in IE?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, watin

I want WatiN to disable JavaScript for some of my tests but can't find any obvious way to do it.

Is it possible?

I am using IE specifically.

Thanks in advance,
Ciaran

Answer (score -1):

You can enable or disable Javascript on different browsers, please check the below link http://mistered.us/tips/javascript/firefox.shtml

You just select the browser type you are using and it will show you the steps.

Enjoy debugging

Comment: Ravia

Thanks for this. I needed to do it programatically, however, so I needed to set the following Registry Key

Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings\\Zones\\2\

SubKey 
1400, 3 ( to disable )
1400, 0 ( to enable )

Comment: I believe ActiveX can do the magic for you.

Try below vbscript:

Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

'Adjust to fit your reg path

WshShell. RegWrite"HKCU\Software\ACME\FortuneTeller\MindReader",
"Goocher!", "REG_SZ"

Answer (score -1):

This isn't possible because, I think, WatiN injects some javascript in the webpage. 
There was a bug in Windows 7 because of that.